# rails format instead of id in url

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have strange problem. In my view I have code like this:

```
= link_to 'Destroy', quests_path(quest), method: :destroy, class: 'btn btn-danger'
```

But my url looks like this in this case:

```
http://localhost:8080/quests.1
```

and in the params I have

```
action: index
controller: web/quests
format: '1'
```

But I need id in the params instead of format.
Please help me.

Edited:
Exactly doesn't work method: :delete.

routes.rb file:

```
scope module: :web do
    root to: 'quests#index'

    match '/logout', to: 'sessions#destroy'

    resources :quests, only: [:new, :create, :index, :destroy] do
      get 'change_state', on: :member
    end
    resource :session, only: [:new, :create, :destroy]

    resource :user, only: [:new, :create, :destroy] do
      scope module: :user do

      end
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 2):

You misspelled in

```
quests_path(quest)
```

correct is

```
quest_path(quest)
```

or just

```
quest
```

Wish it helps

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
= link_to 'Destroy', quest, method: :delete, class: 'btn btn-danger'
```

The reason you get this error is you are passing url to quests#index instead of quests#show/destroy.

Comment: but now I have 'No route matches [GET] "/quests/1"' error. I have not show method and I don't need this. Is it means that 'method: :destroy' doesn't work? How to fix it?

Comment: No route matches [GET] "/quests/1" anyway

Comment: @NikitaKissMe ok it seems your javascript are not working. Please show Are you sure you included your javascripts in your layout?

Comment: Yes, I have this lines in my application layout: = stylesheet_link_tag 'application', :media => "all"
    = javascript_include_tag 'application'

Comment: @NikitaKissMe check your browser console for possible javascript errors.

Answer (score 0):

The link should use the `delete` method, like :

```
= link_to 'Destroy', quest, method: :delete, class: 'btn btn-danger'
```

See http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-link_to